# Why are these picture-related apps blank?

Tags: applications, custom-roms, connection-issues, diagnostics

I've been wondering a lot about this when it happened which I was using `Walli*` app yet after I have changed my ROM, maybe the app gets blank no matter how I install it. But after a time, I've also realized that there is another app called `Reface` with the same problem in which I can't use them because they're blank like there is no connection to the Internet.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Note: I'm using **Cloudflare Family DNS** on my router and Firewall settings such **SPI** and **DOS protection**.
My ROM: `AOSP` based `7.1.`2 Android custom ROM

Comment: Have you tried with other WiFi/mobile data? This may be a connection/network/firewall configuration issue, not an Android issue.

Comment: @AndrewT. Not yet but the other apps are working?

Comment: Well, it depends on where the sources of the images come from, and whether they're blocked by the firewall and/or Cloudflare Family DNS..?

Comment: I don't know yet. However, Cloudflare Family DNS also blocks malware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by installing Exposed via recovery instead of Magisk